# rails specify include columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :resources
end

class Resource < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :resource_images, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :resource_activities, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

The controller:

```
resource = Resource.where(:id => params[:id])
render :json => resource, :include => [:resource_images, :resource_activities, :user], :status => 200
```

Is there a simple way to filter the columns to return from the User Model?

Regards.

Comment: filter which columns ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can do this:

```
render :json => resource, :include => {:resource_images => only: {[:id, :your_column]}, :resource_activities, :user }, :status => 200
```

or use except:

```
render :json => resource, :include => {:resource_images => { except: [:id, :your_column]}, :resource_activities, :user }, :status => 200
```

You can even include methods if you need:

```
render :json => resource, :include => { resource_images: { methods: :thumbnail}, :resource_activities, :user }, :status => 200
```

Here's a really good article if you want to read more: https://quickleft.com/blog/keeping-your-json-response-lean-in-rails/

Comment: You may also consider making a serializer.  [link](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/better-serialization-less-as-json#ItJIet)

Comment: Thanks i like the idea of using except. i'm trying to implement it as follow:     render :json => resource, :include => {:user => { except: [:id, :email]}, :resource_activities, :resource_images }, :status => 200
but i got: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting =>
...:email]}, :resource_activities, :resource_images }, :status ...

any idea?